# No environment variables are available via PHP-fpm+nginx

Tags: php, nginx, environment-variables

I tried to modify php.ini in the following way:

```
variables_order = "GPCSE"
register_globals = On
```

But the required `PATH` variable is neither in `$_ENV` nor accessible via `getenv('PATH')`.
I'm running **Nginx** + **PHP-FPM** on **Ubuntu 10.04**.

**Note:**
executing the following command in console gives a correct result:

```sh
php -r "echo getenv('PATH');"
```

I guess that `PATH` is environment variable of bash, but as long as php-fpm not starting via bash it doesn't have required variables. Any way to include them?

Thanks.

**Update#1**:
As temporary solution I found out that PATH variable stored in '/etc/environment' file. So I just going to read it from there. If someone needs a code:

```
preg_match('/^(PATH)="?([^"]+)"?$/i', file_get_contents('/etc/environment'), $match);
putenv($match[1]."=".$match[2]);
```

Comment: Why did you activate `register_globals`?

Comment: Well, I just tried anything to get it work.

Answer (score 13):

By default, **PHP-FPM** clears the environment variables (from the **www.conf**):

```
; Clear environment in FPM workers
; Prevents arbitrary environment variables from reaching FPM worker processes
; by clearing the environment in workers before env vars specified in this
; pool configuration are added.
; Setting to "no" will make all environment variables available to PHP code
; via getenv(), $_ENV and $_SERVER.
; Default Value: yes
;clear_env = no
```

You can uncomment the last line to set `clear_env` to `no`, but if you prefer, you can set only the environment variables needed:

```
env[PATH] = $PATH
```

Comment: In my case the last flag was'nt evet present. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I came across this problem when upgrading my OwnCloud installation to version 8.1.

They describe a fix in their [documentation](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.1/admin_manual/installation/source_installation.html#configuration-notes-to-php-fpm)

Summary is: Locate your `www.conf` file in your php5-fpm config folder (for Ubuntu this is `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`) and uncomment the needed env[PATH] line.

Optionally update the content of the variable with the output of `php -r "echo getenv('PATH');"`

Answer (score 0):

You could specify it via an include path: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path

You can specify it your php.ini (though you may want a specific path instead of including everything)

> include_path=".:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/fo‌​ta/Development/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130917/sdk/platform-tools "

Comment: PATH is not cwd. My PATH looks like:
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/fota/Development/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130917/sdk/platform-tools

Comment: Sorry, I got confused. it seems like PATH is from linux, do you need to access the string directly or is it just a list of include folders? I've updated my answer to fit the latter in case.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but PATH variable will change from time to time and I didn't want to modify php.ini every time :(
I'm sure there is a way to include bash's environment variable PATH.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was incorrect php-fpm port in nginx configuration: I set fastcgi_pass to 9001 (`pm.status_listen`) instead of 9000 (`listen`). It took me almost the full working day to understand the reason of the problem because the configuration works normally except the one thing: phpfpm does no pass external env vars.