# FFMpeg PHP: Unable to load FFProbe

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg, lumen, bitnami, ffmpeg-php

I am using the Lumen PHP framework which is the form of Laravel. On the server side I have Bitnami.

I get the 500 error when the code that uses FFMpeg is being executed. My part of the code which leads to the problem:

```
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg::create([
            'ffmpeg.binaries'   => '/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg/src/FFMpeg',
            'ffprobe.binaries'  => '/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg/src/FFProbe',
            'timeout' => 0
]);
```

I also tried it without 'timeout'.

Here are the details of the error that I get in the server response:

> ### [ExecutableNotFoundException](#trace-box-2) [ExecutableNotFoundException](#trace-box-1)
>
> ### HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
>
> ## Unable to load FFProbe
>
> #### Exceptions 2
>
> #### FFMpeg\Exception\ExecutableNotFoundException
>
> in /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg/src/FFMpeg/Driver/**FFProbeDriver.php** (line 50)
>
> 45. `$binaries = $configuration->get('ffprobe.binaries', ['avprobe', 'ffprobe']);`
> 46. 
> 47. `try {`
> 48. `return static::load($binaries, $logger, $configuration);`
> 49. `} catch (BinaryDriverExecutableNotFound $e) {`
> 50. `throw new ExecutableNotFoundException('Unable to load FFProbe', $e->getCode(), $e);`
> 51. `}`
> 52. `}`
> 53. `}`

I tried changing the project folder rights by `sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs`. Not sure if it worked. Here is the current state:

> ```
> $ ls -l /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs
> total 328
> drwxrwxrwx 10 bitnami root   4096 Feb 20 16:16 app
> -rwxrwxrwx  1 bitnami root   1094 Feb 20 16:16 artisan
> drwxrwxrwx  2 bitnami root   4096 Feb 20 16:16 bootstrap
> -rwxrwxrwx  1 bitnami root   1076 Jul  2 00:25 composer.json
> -rwxrwxrwx  1 bitnami root 274159 Jul  2 00:25 composer.lock
> drwxrwxrwx  5 bitnami root   4096 Feb 20 16:16 database
> -rwxrwxrwx  1 bitnami root   4871 May 18 15:46 index_default.html
> -rwxrwxrwx  1 bitnami root    592 Feb 20 16:16 phpunit.xml
> drwxrwxrwx  2 bitnami root   4096 Feb 20 16:16 public
> -rwxrwxrwx  1 bitnami root   1920 Feb 20 16:16 README.md
> drwxrwxrwx  3 bitnami root   4096 Feb 20 16:16 resources
> drwxrwxrwx  2 bitnami root   4096 Feb 20 16:16 routes
> drwxrwxrwx  5 bitnami root   4096 Feb 20 16:16 storage
> drwxrwxrwx  2 bitnami root   4096 Feb 20 16:16 tests
> drwxrwxrwx 36 bitnami root   4096 Jul  2 00:46 vendor
> ```

Tried adding this to my .env file in /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs:

> ```
> FFMPEG_BINARIES=/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg/src/FFMpeg
> FFPROBE_BINARIES=/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg/src/FFProbe
> ```

Comment: Is it really named `FFProbe`?  I've never seen anyone name their binaries this way.  It's most likely `ffprobe`.  At the very least, the formal capitalization would be `FFprobe`, but again that's not something people normally name their binaries.

Comment: The path was copied from the file description. I've double-checked the file name, it is certainly FFProbe.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem **'unable to load ffprobe' - laravel/lumen** running on ubuntu nginx and I tried to set binaries path to FFmpeg config but still not working. Then I found my solution in [No environment variables are available via PHP-fpm+nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659675/no-environment-variables-are-available-via-php-fpmnginx) .

In my case, ExecutableFinder (vendor/symfony/process/ExecutableFinder.php)  can't find any path from **getenv('PATH')** .

hope this helps.